# What is the Student Life Office of Student Services?

Tags: meaning

Student activities at Central European University are organized directly by the students, by their academic departments or by **the Student Life Office of Student Services**.

Answer (score 1):

Here **student Life office** means an office that directs it's activities towards student Life. Like its objective may be to formulate policies to regulate a student's study time, playing time, a code of conduct describing how a student should behave with others etc.